# Are bad things more likely to happen on Erev Tisha B’av than any other time of year?

Tags: tisha-bav, nine-days, three-weeks

Are bad things inclined to happen today? I was thinking about going on a bike ride today, but I don’t trust Erev Tisha B’Av, so I don’t think I will. I feel like there’s a negative energy and that we don’t get as much rachmanis from Hashem.

Comment: Does [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/115572/why-do-bad-things-happen-to-us-on-tisha-bav-in-particular?rq=1]) answer your question?